# access files on android device from pc through usb

Tags: java, android, usb, usb-drive

I know it is possible to access and transfer files from a computer to an android device using `adb`, but is there a way of transferring a file from an android device to a computer through the usb cable without using the adb tool? The transfer should be made through the usb cable, I don't have the option of bluetooth or wireless.

Using `adb` is not an option because the computer to which the file would be transferred must have the Android SDK installed, or at least the `adb` tool.

At this moment I consider writing a daemon which will run on the computer, detect when a device has connected and transfer the file. Is is possible to accomplish this without running a daemon on the computer (i.e. directly from the phone) ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Mostley, you can use the built-in USB service from android. If you plugin your device, and it is correctly installed, your phone should ask you for mass-storage.

Also, it depends on your phone. What phone do you have?